# Git apply patch file can't file the file location

Tags: git, patch

Apologies if this is a silly question but I want to create a patch file based on the differences between the files. Thing is two files are located in different paths given they are of the same name. I ran the following

```
git diff ../../../../../../external/freertos/source/include/FreeRTOS.h ../../../../SystemView\ Patched\ files/FreeRTOS.h > freertosconf.patch
```

The patch file is created fine but applying a patch errors out:

```
error: invalid path '../../../../../../external/freertos/source/include/FreeRTOS.h'
```

The top of the patch file

```
diff --git a/../../../../../../external/freertos/source/include/FreeRTOS.h b/../../../../SystemView Patched files/FreeRTOS.h
```

Does anyone see the obvious issue here?

Comment: *Does anyone see the obvious issue here?* how about: `a/../../../../../../` has six too many `/..` parts in it... The `b` part has a lot of pointless `../` as well. Git likes its path names to be of the form `a/<where to find file before> b/<where to find file after>`.

Comment: `<where to find file before>` is the same as what's being provided in `git diff` command though

Comment: Only it's not: you're using files that are *outside the repository*. In-repository path names never have `../` after the `a/` or `b/` part. (If you're below the top level of the repository, the diff output has the resolved paths relative to the root. You *can* override that with the various prefix options, but if you do, it's your responsibility to fix up the diff text for consumption by a later Git command.)

Comment: So is the preferred way around it to have the files in the same location?

Comment: Do you actually have a Git repository or are you just using the `git diff` command to create a patch (unrelated to a repository)?

Comment: I am running `git apply` inside the folder that has git repo initialized already

Comment: I don't know about *preferred*. On the rare occasion when I have had to do something like this, I just open up the `git diff` file in my editor and fix the pathnames. `git apply` has a `-p` flag to change how many parts it strips (the default is 1, stripping the `a/` and `b/`) but I just replace `a/this/that/the/other` with `a/correct/path/to/file` for instance and I'm good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "**--unsafe-paths**" switch in git apply if you plan on leaving the working directory with ../../../../../../

Note: After git version 2.4.0 there were tweaks in the safety of using git apply.

From https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.4.0.txt:

> - "git apply" was not very careful about reading from, removing,
>   updating and creating paths outside the working tree (under
>   --index/--cached) or the current directory (when used as a
>   replacement for GNU patch).
>   (merge e0d201b jc/apply-beyond-symlink later to maint).

Answer (score -1):

Just copy the file to replace the file and generate the diff with git diff

```
cp ../../../../../../external/freertos/source/include/FreeRTOS.h ../../../../SystemView\ Patched\ files/FreeRTOS.h

git diff ../../../../SystemView\ Patched\ files/FreeRTOS.h > freertosconf.patch
```

PS: why not running this in a top directory to avoid `./../../../`

Comment: `../../../../SystemView\ Patched\ files/` is not a git repo though, hence why I was only running in a directory which is git initialized.

Comment: none of the two files are on a git repo ?

Comment: one (`../../../../../../external/freertos/source/include/FreeRTOS.h`) is, the other isn't.